# Symfony 2 forms: array of entities

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping

I am trying to build a form for multiple entities. Let me first introduce some sample classes:

For clarity I do not show all annotations or abbreviate them, and I do not show the use or namespace commands.

```
/**
 * The Entity class
 * @ORM ... mapping to ORM
 */
class EntityA {
    /**
     * @var ModelArray
     * @ORM\Column(name="...", type="object") 
     */
    private $modelArray;

    // Getters and Setters, default constructor
}

/**
 * An array Wrapper, keeping the array always unique, sorting it by criteria etc.
 * @ORM(...) 
 */
class ModelArray {
    /**
     * @var array<A>
     */
    private $array; 

    // Getter, Adder, Remover, Constructor, other private logic
}
```

Notice especially that the class ModelArray stores only objects of a given Type A:

```
/**
 * One more Model
 */
class A {
    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $bool;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $string;

    // Getters, Setters
}
```

I chose this data structure, because I never need objects of A to exist outside the EntityA class, and to keep the logic out of my Entity, I chose to implement the ModelArray class in between. The EntityA class is persisted to a database, and with it the child objects.

Now I want to create a form, where I can edit the $->bool attributes of all A instances of an Array of EntityA at once.
So what I provide is `array<EntityA>`.

I would then proceed as follows:

```
//In a controller action
$data = array(
    'as' => $arrayOfEntityA,    
);
$form = $this->createForm(new GridType(), $data);
// Create view, render
```

My form type would look like this:

```
class GridType extends AbstractType {

    public function getName() {
        return 'a_grid';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('as', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new GridAType(),
        ));
    }
}
```

And use this form type

```
class GridAType extends AbstractType {

    public function getName() {
        return 'a_grid_a';
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('modelArray', new ModelArrayType());
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'EntityA',
        );
    }
}
```

With the model array type

```
class ModelArrayType extends AbstractType {



    public function getName() {
        return 'model_array';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        // ???
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'ModelArray',
        );
    }
}
```

Notice the `// ???`: I would like to only edit the boolean attribute of the As strored in the ModelArray, and I think the appropriate form type to continue would be a 'collection'. But I can't really find out how to use the array (`$modelArray->array`)here as a collection.
How should I do this?

An then, I'm not entirely sure if it is good practice to implement such a lot of form types just to achieve one usable form. Is there a different and better way?